# Gparted merge ext4 partition to ext4 partition

Tags: partitioning

How can I merge that ext4 patition I used for compiling software that I no longer need to another main Linux ext4 partition?

I've booted into Live CD /Lubuntu/ and started Gparted and I see all the partitions I have.

So,I want to merge all the space from @LinuxCompilerPar (/dev/sda5) to @LinuxPartition (/dev/sda7)

How can I achieve this?

[image: All the partitions on my HD]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, merge normally means you want to keep the data, but in this case I understand you don't want to.  You just want to recover the **space** that /dev/sda7 uses up.

The issue here, is obviously, that you have the swap partition in between these.  There are many ways to solve this, but the first thing I need to know is what partition is the one that you want to *keep*.  From your explanation, I understand the important data is on /dev/sda7 and the data that may be deleted is on /dev/sda5.  Frankly, it would be easier if it's the inverse, but, I'll go with this.

What I would do, in this particular case is:

- Delete the linux-swap
- Delete /dev/sda5
- You now have a slab of free disk space before /dev/sda7
- Move /dev/sda7 to the front of the extended partition.  (Takes a long time)
- Resize /dev/sda7 so it takes everything minus 1GB (Takes a long time)
- Create a new linux-swap at the end of the disk.
- Reboot

At this point everything should be fine.  Your system might complain about unmountable filesystems and you it will most certainly not use the swap partition you recreated.

To do this, you add the new swap partition to your /etc/fstab and remove the old one.  Basically, identify the block id of your new swap partition:

```
$ blkid /dev/sdaX 
/dev/sdaX: UUID="12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012" TYPE="swap"
```

in your /etc/fstab replace the UUID for the swap:

```
UUID=abcdef01-abcd-ef01-abcd-abcdef012345 none swap sw 0 0
```

becomes

```
UUID=12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012 none swap sw 0 0
```

After that, either reboot or issue

```
$ sudo swapon -a
```

I don't know how you've been using /dev/sda7, but you might want to remove it from /etc/fstab before doing anything.  If all this confuses you, start off with posting the content of /etc/fstab and I'll try elucidate things.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy, as long as you're okay with all the data on `/dev/sda5` being deleted.

**WARNING**: Though there should be no data loss (except for the data on `/dev/sda5`), operations on partitions are always dangerous. You should have a backup before continuing.

1. Click on `/dev/sda5` and click the delete button (the trash can icon on the toolbar)
2. Click on `/dev/sda5` (the new `/dev/sda5`, your swap partition) and click on the resize/move button. Set the free space preceding to 1 and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The space should be moved to the "Free space following" box. Click "Resize/Move".
3. Click on `/dev/sda6` and click on the resize/move button. Set the new size to the maximum size and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Click "Resize/Move".
4. Click on the apply button (the check mark icon on the toolbar) and click "Apply".

Comment: The issue with moving a partition is that it takes a long time.  A swap file has no important data and it's quicker to delete and recreate.  Granted, it's only 1GB, so it will probably not be the biggest deal.
Also, I'm not sure if gparted renumbers the partitions immediately.  It's been a while I used it.

He should look into lvm for future installations---

Comment: @jawtheshark Moving a partition only takes a long time if it has lots of data on it. The swap partition will have no data on it unless you're using it (in which case you won't be able to move or delete it anyway). gparted does renumber the partitions immediately (I tested all of this on a VM before posting it).

Comment: Unless gparted became significantly smarter in the last years, it's stupid enough to basically do the equivalent of a dd on a swap partion.

Comment: @jawtheshark I just tried it; it took less than a second.

Comment: In that case the move is the smarter thing to do.  It also avoids having to meddle with /etc/fstab. Probably still needs to do that because of the /dev/sda7 going missing.  Normally Ubuntu should use UUIDs so the renumbering of the sd devices doesn't affect fstab.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to delete /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda6, then re-create your swap partition /dev/sda6 inside /dev/sda4 so that it fits from the beginning of /dev/sda4 and in the end extend /dev/sda7 to fill /dev/sda4